# Assign a pointer in a char array to each word in a string C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a array of chars that is a maximum of 200 characters. I would like to assign an array of points to each word in the array. I have this picture as an example of what is supposed to happen.
[I am not allowed to post images so here is a link to the picture on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSfFZ.png)

I have tried looping over the string looking for white spaces, assigning a new pointer to each occurrence. But then it prints the remaining string each time and then crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[200];
    char *arr[200];
    fgets(str, 200, stdin);
    arr[1] = &str[5];
    printf("%s", arr[1]);
    int i = 0;
    int next = 0;
    char ch = ' ';
    for (; i < 200; i++) {
        ch = str[i];
        if (ch == ' '){
            arr[next] = &str[i];
            next++;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    for (; i < 200; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, it looks like `strtok` may be useful in this situation.

Comment: We can't help with code we can't see.

Comment: I have, I would like, .. How about posting your code so far?

Comment: Interesting things will happen if you replace that discovered whitespace char with a 0-char terminator. Even better things will happen if you use [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) rather than reinventing this already-quite-circular wheel.

Comment: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/PjK9FS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample to fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[200];
    char *arr[sizeof(str)/2];//Enough if half
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    int i, j;
    char ch = ' ';
    for (j = i = 0; str[i] && str[i] != '\n'; i++) {//i < 200 is over run.
        if(ch == ' ' && str[i] != ' ')
            arr[j++] = &str[i];
        ch = str[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {//i < 200 is over run.
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[200];
    char *arr[sizeof(str)/2];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    int i, j=0;
    char *word = strtok(str, " \t\n");
    while(word){
        arr[j++] = word;
        word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is how I thought my code would work, but what I'm trying to achieve is to get it to print word for word and not the rest of the string after each white space.

Comment: @TheMethodMan Needs to be changed to '\0' after the word to not print the remaining characters. `strtok` is useful in such processes as has been pointed out already.

Comment: @TheMethodMan i add sample by strtok.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fewer than 200 whitespaces in your content, the output loop will grab a pointer to a random address from arr[i] and supply it to printf... that could cause your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) if the string is modifyable you can change the first whitespace character after each word to '\0'. This will let you print using the pointers you store, but the original string won't print properly anymore.

2) store the length of the string and the pointer in a struct, and have a custom function the can print them for you.

Comment: It seems strtok does #1